# How to package and send an android app

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have used Android Studio to build my Android App. I have found numerous tutorials for generating the apk file, but now that I have done that how do I send my app to somebody? The apk file is called app-release.apk. It doesn't even show the name of my app. Can I change the name? Can I package it somehow and add an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APK is the file that you use to install an app in some Android device. If you have an APK file, it is already packaged, just send it to your friend.

And yes, you can change the file name, but that will not have any kind of effect on the app, it is just changing the file name...

Comment: So I only send the file that says app-release.apk? It just has a white rectangular icon.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by package it??

You can surely change the name by RENAMING it . And as for the icon you can add an image to the `drawable` folder and then set the icon for it.

The icon can be set in the `ActivityManifest` file. Here is how to do it--

In the android manifest file there is a `android:icon` just set the location of your image .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x30x.png

Comment: I have the icon in my app and it shows when I run it on my phone. I just thought that when I went through the process of generating an apk I would end up with a file that at least had the same name as my app and with an icon that looked more like something from Android.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the application is stored in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
  android:label="NAME OF APPLICATION"
```

You can rename the .APK file to anything you like, it does not change the name of the application.

The APK file can be sent to others for installation.

Answer (score 1):

The apk file is only recognized on an android system. Any other system (Windows for example) wouldn't bother trying to show the app's icon even if you set it properly in the manifest. As for renaming it, you can rename it to whatever you want as long as you keep the apk extension. The real app name that will show when installed is set in your manifest file. And packaging it? you already done that by generating the apk! However if the person receiving your app wants to install it, it has to enable "Unknown sources" in `Setting > Security > Unknown sources` as your application is not coming from the play store.